# spring batch job complete. Now how i do use metadata and admin console

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I've got a spring mvc web application and have just integrated my first spring batch job into the application and it works!).

I have not run the create_metadata script yet to create the metadata tables. Once I do run that script how can I make sure the metadata for my job gets put into the meta data tables? Do I need to do anything special in the spring config files or should it just work?

I also want to include the admin console into my mvc application. What do i need to do in order to achieve this?

Thanks for your help. Sorry for the novice questions.

Answer (score 2):

Probably now you are using a [MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html) that works in memory and doesn't persist data.
Move to [JobRepositoryFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.html) and run create_metadata script; metadata will be stored automatically by SB during execution.
Your job is to cleanup older jobs metadata when space occupied by those data will grow up too much.

I have never work with admin console and can't help you.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was using JobRepositoryFactoryBean. I will try to switch over. thank you